# Conditional WHERE clause on an Entity Framework context

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

```
objRecord = await _context.Persons
    .Where(tbl => tbl.DeletedFlag == false)
    .ToListAsync();
```

This is the EF code I've got which successfully gets all the records from the `Person` table where `DeletedFlag` is false.

I want to add another where criteria that if a surname has been passed in, then add the extra where clause

```
.Where(tbl => tbl.Surname.Contains(theSurname))
```

I've tried IQueryable and some other options but can't figure out how to do the equivalent of

```
string theSurname = "";
objRecord = await _context.Persons
    .Where(tbl => tbl.DeletedFlag == false)
    if ( theSurname != "") {
        .Where(tbl => tbl.Surname.Contains(theSurname))
    }
    .ToListAsync();
```

which obviously doesn't work as you can't put an if statement in an EF call.

I can add a criteria afterwards that limits objRecord, but I don't want to retrieve all the records, then cut it down, I'd rather only get the records I need.

Comment: Use `.Where(tbl => tbl.DeletedFlag == false && tbl.Surname.Contains(theSurname))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine conditions in the `Where` method by just adding `tbl.Surname.Contains(theSurname)` so your final query will look like below:

```
objRecord = await _context.Persons
                          .Where(tbl => tbl.DeletedFlag == false && 
                                        tbl.Surname.Contains(theSurname))
                          .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: You have posted the same answer after mine. Why?

Comment: @viveknuna that doesn't prove he see your answer :-)

Comment: @CodeNotFound but posting the same answer is not a good practice

Comment: @viveknuna you can delete yours too as long as the OP already choose this one. A lot question already have a duplicated answer just because the poster doesn't see other answers. Answers are not loaed automaticcally when you're adding yours.. ;-)

Comment: Wow you are supporting this, great. Salute you

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply logical AND (`&&`) with the existing condition in Where clause i.e. `tbl.Surname.Contains(theSurname)`;

So your query would be

```
.Where(tbl => tbl.DeletedFlag == false && tbl.Surname.Contains(theSurname));
```