# Conditional ORDER BY clause on an Entity Framework context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

As an extension to my last question 
[Conditional WHERE clause on an Entity Framework context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50841429/conditional-where-clause-on-an-entity-framework-context)

This is the EF code I've got which successfully gets all the records from the Person table where DeletedFlag is false

```
objRecord = await _context.Persons
    .Where(tbl => tbl.DeletedFlag == false && tbl.Surname.Contains(theSurname))
    .ToListAsync();
```

I now want to conditionally sort the resultset in either ascending or descending order based on other criteria.   I can add additional code after the above like so

```
if (sortorder == "asc") {
    objRecord =  objRecord.OrderBy(tbl => tbl.Surname).ToList();
} else {
    objRecord =  objRecord.OrderByDescending(tbl => tbl.Surname).ToList();
}
```

which will sort the list and store it back into itself, but wondered if there's a way to add the sort order criteria within the initial call.

EDIT

The "this is a duplicate" link points to a LINQ example that works the way my second code section does

```
if (sortorder == "asc") {
    objRecord =  objRecord.OrderBy(tbl => tbl.Surname).ToList();
} else {
    objRecord =  objRecord.OrderByDescending(tbl => tbl.Surname).ToList();
}
```

**which is what I'm trying to avoid**

Well read admins!